# array of classes overwriting

Tags: java, arrays

When im making array of classes, each element of previous class is overwritten by next class elements.

Thats my class:

```
public class Perceptron2 {

    public double prog=0.01;
    public double wagi[]=new double[35];
    public double blad;
    public double stala=0.001;
    public Perceptron2(double prog, double[] wagi, double blad) {
        this.prog = prog;
        this.wagi = wagi;
        this.blad = blad;
        stala=0.001;
    }
    public double getProg() {
        return prog;
    }
    public void setProg(double prog) {
        this.prog = prog;
    }

    public double[] getWagi() {
        return wagi;
    }

    public void setWagi(double[] wagi) {
        this.wagi = wagi;
    }

    public double getBlad() {
        return blad;
    }

    public void setBlad(double blad) {
        this.blad = blad;
    }

    public double getStala() {
        return stala;
    }

    public void setStala(double stala) {
        this.stala = stala;
    }

}
```

And following code

```
public class runn {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        double [] wagi = new double[35];
        double prog = 0.01;     
        Perceptron2[] p = new Perceptron2[10];
        System.out.println(p.length);
        for (int i=0;i<p.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<35; j++) 
            {
                wagi[j]=random.nextDouble()*0.1;
            }
            System.out.println(i+" "+wagi[1]);
            p[i] = new Perceptron2 (prog, wagi , 0.01);
        }
        System.out.println(p[3].wagi[1]);
        System.out.println(p[4].wagi[1]);
    }
}
```

For example p[3].wagi[1] and p[4].wagi[1] are equal. How to make them different?

Comment: You're not making an array of classes, you're making an array of *instances* of classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects (including arrays) are passed as pointers in Java, not as copies of their contents.

You need to make a new instance of `wagi` for every iteration of the outer loop.

As it is, you are stuffing the same `wagi` into each `Perceptron2` (another sentence I never thought I would write).

So either

```
for (int i=0;i<p.length;i++){
   double [] wagi = new double[35];
   for(int j=0; j<35; j++) {
```

or in the Perceptron2 constructor make a defensive copy of the array:

```
this.wagi = Arrays.copyOf(wagi, wagi.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Into main method, change for this line:

```
p[i] = new Perceptron2 (prog, new double[35], 0.01);
```

Put it at the begining of the loop. And into the loop, set the value at the correct place in array by doing:

```
 p[i].wagi[j]=random.nextDouble()*0.1;
```

Your problem is due to use of same instance of wagi for each Perceptron object.

Answer (score 0):

in "runn.class", remove this line,

```
double [] wagi = new double[35];
```

and put it under the outer for loop like this

```
for (int i=0;i<p.length;i++)
    {
        double [] wagi = new double[35];
        for(int j=0; j<35; j++) 
        {
            wagi[j]=random.nextDouble()*0.1;
        }
        System.out.println(i+" "+wagi[1]);
        p[i] = new Perceptron2 (prog, wagi , 0.01);
    }
```